# Electron Vertex in Fourth Order

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I was trying to solve some integrals that appear in quantum electrodynamics but I was not able to do it on my own.

$$1/6\int_0^1 \int_0^1 { u^3 z^2(1-z^2/3)  \over [u^2(1-z^2)+4(1-u)]}dudz $$

I know the answer should be $$(\pi^2 / 18) - (115 / 216)$$

Can anyone help me solve this or at least point me to a book that might cover those double integrals?
I would realy appreciate it. In attachment you have an image of the paper this came from. Of course I have problems with the other integrals too. But I chose to start with this one.

Thank you.

[Extract of paper by Soto, 1970 - Calculation of the Slope at q2=0 of the Dirac Form Factor for the Electron Vertex in Fourth Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWdI9.png)

Comment: Hint : your integral can be written $\frac16 \int _0^1\int _0^1 u \frac{z^2(1-z^2/3)}{a^2-z^2}dudz$ with $a:=\frac{u-2}{u}$ then separated into the sum of two rather classical integrals.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Did you mean to do variable replacement of u by a? I did that and got $${2\over3}\int_0^1 \int_{-\infty}^{-1}{z^2(1-{1\over3}z^2 )\over {(a^2-z^2)(a-1)^3}}dadz$$. Is that correct? I am not sure how to divide it into two integrals... Could you please let me know which two integrals should I get? I appreciate any assistance you can give me. Thank you very much.